# Cheap 1" LCD suitable for use with microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, lcd

What cheap LCD pixel displays are available which are 1" or smaller which could be interfaced to a microcontroller? (AVR, PIC24, etc.)

I'd like to make an interactive keyfob.

The important factor is small size, 1.5"^2 maximum.

I've seen small colour displays in LCD keychains which look ideal - but, it looks as though they use some custom controller logic which only talks USB.

[image]
[image]

Something like these 16x16 monochrome LCDs would be ok, if I could find a display controllable with SPI (this device has a custom epoxied blob).

http://img.skitch.com/20090406-8dargu3hrnwdnfpgdu35k3tu78.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: On Alibaba.com:`Home > Products > Electronic Components & Supplies > Optoelectronic Displays > LCD Modules`, then choose `Graphic` for >2000 hits. Have fun browsing! :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A guy named Rossum (known for the world's [smallest, cheapest game console](https://rossumblog.com/2010/10/25/building-the-rbox/)
 [[prev url](https://web.archive.org/web/20130420164211/http://rossum.posterous.com/building-the-rbox)]) did a nice job of reviewing and reverse engineering lots of [cheap LCD displays](https://rossumblog.com/2010/10/13/screen-play-lots-of-other-screens-for-microcontrollers/) [[prev url](https://web.archive.org/web/20130420164211/http://rossum.posterous.com/screen-play-lots-of-other-screens-for-microco)]. In his latest post he reverse engineered an [iPod Nano 2g display](https://rossumblog.com/2010/11/17/a-smarter-display/) [[prev url](https://web.archive.org/web/20130420164211/http://rossum.posterous.com/a-smarter-display)].

Answer (score 6):

Sparkfun sells these:

http://www.sparkfun.com/products/569

Comment: Cool... I'm gonna buy one of these! Thanks (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Could you not salvage one from an old nokia(or other phone)? Such as the 3310. This [instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Connecting-Nokia-3310-LCD-to-USB-using-AVR/) has a nice tutorial on the Nokia LCD and ATMega8. Just found this [site](http://www.amontec.com/lcd_nokia_3310.shtml) that has useful information on sizing and pin layouts for the screen.
[image: Nokia 3310]

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be LCD? I have used some OLED displays with a micro-controller before. I have gotten them from http://www.osddisplays.com/

Answer (score 1):

I usually check [EarthLCD](http://www.earthlcd.com) to see what they have available.  They tend to have a pretty good selection of small LCDs, and I have purchased many from them in the past.  I can't really comment on how good their prices are, but they at least have what I need.

They don't have any in stock right now, but I purchased a 1.5" color Seiko LCD from them before, part #RNH942209R1A.  $15.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a "programmable display pushbutton" as a combined display and user interface.

http://www.sparkfun.com/search/results?term=screenkey&what=products

http://www.nkksmartswitch.com/

http://www.nkkswitches.com/SmartSwitch-Development-Tools.aspx

They are extremely small.
They can be programmed with 4 wire SPI.
Alas, they are not exactly what I would call "cheap".
Still, fulfilling 2 out of 3 wishes is pretty good ...